# How can I prevent Visual Studio from scrolling down to the bottom of the file when pasting a snippet of text?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When inserting a copied text in Visual Studio 2010 via CTRL+V, the text is pasted, and VS automatically scrolls down to the bottom of the file.
I've encountered this at least for XAML and C# files.

Any ideas on how to de-activate this scrolling?

Comment: Do you mean it scrolls down to the end of the *inserted text*? Or the bottom of the entire file?

Comment: To the bottom of the entire file.

Comment: @ChrissBaumann: I'm seing the exact same behavior in VS2012. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643664/prevent-visual-studio-to-scroll-to-the-end-of-file-when-pressing-ctrl-a-select . It looks like there's no way to disable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to "options"-->"keyboard" and check if there is such a keyboard shortcut enabled.
You can try to reset this settings if you don't find.

Comment: That didn´t change the behaviour. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This was happening on my VS 2019 only within CSS `<style>` tag. I've resolved it using the following setting:

[image]