# Prevent Visual Studio to scroll to the end of file when pressing Ctrl A (select all)

Tags: visual-studio

It's basically in the title.

Whenever you "select all" in the Visual Studio code editor, the editor will scroll down to the bottom of the file. Is there a way to prevent this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 at the moment, but this applies to all versions.

Comment: What about placing a bookmark in the file and returning to it after your operation is done?

Comment: Yes, I've been using that sometimes... still it's kind of impractical for me. I wish I could just get the same "non-scrolling" behaviour that most text editors (like Sublime Text) have into Visual Studio. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: No, this is fundamental about the way text selection works.  The editor always puts the caret at the start or end of the selection.  From where you can alter the selection by holding down the Shift key.  The window scrolls to make the caret visible.  It has no other text selection mode, nothing like the "persistent block" mode that some editors have.  No point in looking for an alternative.

Comment: Well, Sublime Text for example will also put the caret at the end of the document, but it doesn't scroll to that position. So I was hoping that there might be a setting for this in Visual Studio as well... Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 still does this. This is so annoying because I have a habit of pressing Ctrl+S unconsciously to prevent potential work losses, and sometimes I often press Ctrl+A instead of Ctrl+S, and I lose the location I was working at. If there is no other way, I think I will change the shortcut for 'select all'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot change this behavior.

Microsoft has been aware of this since at least VS 2010, but either doesn't think it's a bug or doesn't think it's important enough to fix.

From their response to a 2010 bug report filed on the issue:

> We unfortunately do not plan to change Ctrl+A's scrolling at this
>   time, so we're unfortunately resolving this issue as Won't Fix for VS
>   2010. However, it will remain in our database to be revisited for a future release of Visual Studio.

Source: [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597742/ctrl-a-always-scrolls-to-the-bottom-of-the-document)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I added that bug to my watch list since you can't vote on it anymore (hopefully someone will notice some people dislike the behavior).

Comment: It's VS2022 and still won't fix. Every other code editor supports this.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Ctrl-Z-Ctrl-Y will get you back to where you were. If you tend to do a Ctrl-S Ctrl-A Ctrl-C a lot then just get used to this whole chain instead: Ctrl-SACZY. Or, create a macro: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Even if the link was removed, this would still be an answer (just a lame one suggesting undo/redo as a workaround).

Comment: If there are other workarounds, feel free to suggest one that is less "lame".

Comment: @DriveByGuy I quite like this answer (despite its lameness) because as pointed out, there doesn't seem to be a better way. Although I have been thrown off a few times by the fact that this solution returns to the most recently edited line, not necessarily the line in focus.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this myself, but the "undo" suggestion gave me an idea and I feel kinda dumb for not thinking of it earlier.  Visual Studio includes "Navigate Backwards" and "Navigate Forwards" buttons (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, respectively).  So after you finish selecting and copying, simple click the navigate backwards button or type <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and voilà! you're back where you were.

I know it doesn't stop the scroll to begin with, but at least it puts your cursor back *exactly* where you left it!